# add class "selected"

Tags: jquery, html, css

hello guys i have the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.shoppers-images ul li').click(function () {
            $('.shoppers-images ul li').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
    });
```

this works as i wish... but i am sure that the css is wrong because it is overwriting some declared values .. and the .selected class will never show

```
#foot-transport{
    background: url(../img/css/register-runner.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#bicycle-transport{
    background: url(../img/css/register-bycicle.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#van-transport{
    background: url(../img/css/register-van.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
 .selected{
   background: url(../img/css/checked-image.png) no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
}
```

this is my html:

```
<div class="span7 shoppers-images">
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li id="foot-transport"><span>Individual</span></li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li id="bicycle-transport"><span>Pro Driver/Courier</span></li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li id="van-transport"><span>A Delivery </span></li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

the question is: how can i declare my "selected" class in css so that it will be stronger?

Comment: you are removing and adding same class for same dom.

Comment: You have malformed HTML. `<a>` elements are not valid children of a `<ul>`

Comment: Check this about specyfity: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ it will clear things and make you understand it better. – scx 7 mins ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS ID selectors take precedence over classname selectors. You can use the `!important` rule:

```
.selected{
   background: url(../img/css/checked-image.png) no-repeat !important;
   background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to assist.

Comment: You can easily omit `background-position` from `.selected` because it doesn't differ from what's already defined on these elements.

Comment: !important is not recommended

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is under this circumstance.

Comment: Do not use !important unless you have to. Its always better to build more complex selectors then using !important.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
.shoppers-images ul:nth-child(1){   //#foot-transport
background: url(../img/css/register-runner.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    margin-right: 20px;

}
```

### and same for all so specificity can work id have more precedence then class

```
 .shoppers-images ul li.selected{
       background: url(../img/css/checked-image.png) no-repeat;
       background-position: center center;
    }
```

`!important` is not recommended

specificity is perfect

here the specificity is 22 and in your case it is 10

Comment: in this context the user select the element from class .shoppers-images ul li

Comment: check yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/gFnxb/ your .shoppers-images ul li.selected gets overridden by #id , and this solves it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check this out. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Specyfity of id element is higher then class selected in your css selectors. Thats why your element is overriden with anothers styles.

Try this for example

```
 #foot-transport{
    background: url(../img/css/register-runner.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
    #bicycle-transport{
    background: url(../img/css/register-bycicle.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
    #van-transport{
    background: url(../img/css/register-van.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
 #foot-transport.selected,#bicycle-transport.selected, #van-transport.selected,{
   background: url(../img/css/checked-image.png) no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
}
```

Using id and a class will make it more important and show. 
You may also use !important but its not recommended, only in specyfic situation and only when you cant afford doing it better.

```
.selected {
    background: url(../img/css/checked-image.png) no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center center !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because ID selectors take priority over classes. You will need to make the selector more specific.

**CSS**

```
#transport-links .selected {
    background: url(../img/css/checked-image.png) no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="transport-links" class="span7 shoppers-images">
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li id="foot-transport"><span>Individual</span></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li id="bicycle-transport"><span>Pro Driver/Courier</span></li></a>
        <a href="#"><li id="van-transport"><span>A Delivery </span></li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can use `!important` though it is considered bad practice.

**Further reading**

- [Smashing Magazine - CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)